# Grails createCriteria group by

Tags: grails

How can I get something like this MYSQL query with createCriteria in grails?

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM engine4_user_fields_values
     WHERE field_id = 31 OR field_id = 24 
  GROUP BY item_id;
```

It works fine if I use something like this:

```
def items = items_c.list{
        'in'('fieldId',field_ids)
        projections{
            groupProperty("itemId")
        }
    }
```

But I need to define order, max and sort field like this:

```
def items = items_c.list(max:5, sort:"itemId", order:"desc"){
        'in'('fieldId',field_ids)
        projections{
            groupProperty("itemId")
        }
    }
```

But this gets me different rows with the same 'item_id'

What can I do?

Comment: It might make sense to consider using a HQL query. Can you update the question include the fields of the domain class(es) relevant to the engine4_user_fields_values table?

Comment: What happens if you add groupProperty('fieldId') below your first groupProperty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about listDistinct{} ?

[http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.4.2 Criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.4.2%20Criteria)

Comment: True, but that doesn't seem to be a requirement here?

Answer (score 0):

Use the projection agains the first result,

```
  lists= items.createCriteria().list(){
  projections {
  order ("ItemId")
  }

  }
```

or executeQuery("your Query Here"); with distnict