# How to use "Grouped BY" with Grails criteria among three tables

Tags: grails, criteria, join

If I have three domain classes like this:

```
class Candidate  {
    static belongsto=[application:Application]

}


class Vote {
   String name;
static belongsto=[application:Application]

}

class Application {


    Date datedemand;
   Candidate candidates; 
     Vote votes
    static hasMany = [candidates:Candidate,votes:Vote]

}
```

I want to retrieve **all candidates grouped by Vote's Name .**

I started ​​the following attempt, and I remain blocked :

```
def criteria =  Application.createCriteria()
def results = criteria.list { 
    votes {

     }
    candidates{


    }

}
```

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598436/grails-createcriteria-group-by)

Comment: Thanks . But, It's not useful .

Answer (score 0):

In decent grails (2.x+) you could try something similar:

```
Application.withCriteria {
   createAlias("votes", votes)
   projections {
      groupProperty("votes.name")
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is valid. First, `votes.name` is not valid. `name` is a property of `vote` instead of `votes`. Second, he needs "all **candidates** grouped by Vote's Name".

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario I would go for a simple vanilla HQL instead of Criteria, something like this or more (use `join` the way you need):

```
String hql = "Select V.name, C.name " + 
             "from Candidate C, Vote V " + 
             "where C.application = V.application " +
             "group by V.name, C.name"

Query query = session.createQuery(hql)
List results = query.list()
```